# why does nginx delete files from cache?

Tags: nginx

I have set max_size=2000m and inactive=1440h.

In spite of this nginx keeps deleting files from cache although the cache is only 120Mb.

None of the files under my cache folder are over a week old.

Any idea why?

Comment: Please post the relevant snippets from your nginx.conf

Answer (score 1):

Please read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html documentation about caching.

```
Cached data that are not accessed during the time specified by the
inactive parameter get removed from the cache regardless of their freshness.
```

So, i suppose, you cache exists more than 60 days. Some files for that time never be accessed, and were removed.

Comment: None of the files under my cache folder are over a week old. Can there be any other reason?