# How to set Nginx cache to never expire on server side

Tags: nginx

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833056/why-does-nginx-delete-files-from-cache).

I have also read the [proxy_cache_path setting page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path) setting, where it specified that by default, **inactive is set to 10 minutes**.

So is it possible to set it to infinity which makes it never to be expired? It is a read only data and I hope I could save the cache.

Comment: I have set **inactive=1440h** and clear cache before I do some load test, but the cache did not even last one day, as I see the size is increased 
 and then reduced in the same day.

Comment: Setting used : **proxy_cache_path /home/xxx/nginx-tmp levels=1:2 keys_zone=api_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=1440h use_temp_path=off;**

Comment: I found out the files are being deleted while there is no traffic, and the inactive is set to 1440h and it is being removed in less than 6 hours, why is nginx worker process deleting my files?